# jsp expression and java script together

Tags: javascript, jsp, expression

I have defined label in my jsp as ,

```
<label id='mylabel'>
```

and I am setting some text to it dynamically as,

```
<%if(somecondtion){%>
   <script>document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML ="Your payement processed";
<%}%>
```

But now here I want to add payment date from database as ,Your payement processed on 2012-08-10.Please verify.

So i tried like,

```
 <%if(somecondtion){
    Date myDate = retrieved date from DB; // Here I have retrieved date from DB which   is like 2012-08-10
  %>
  <script>document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML ="Your payement processed on    "+<%=myDate%>. "Please verify.";
  <%}%>
```

Its not working..I tried couple of ways..sometimes its gives error as ; missing.Sometimes it shows date as 1988.Cant it be possible java script and jsp expression together for date ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that the date is part of the JavaScript string:

```
<script>document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML ="Your payment processed on <%=myDate%>. Please verify.";
```

No need to "add" the date, in other words. Just emit it in the middle of the JavaScript string, and it'll be there when the code is evaluated on the client.